# Integrate CSS to WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to add the effect from [this site](https://www.canva.com/) to my WordPress site (blur effect). I already got the script and the CSS file and I already integrated the script to my site. But my problem is now how can I add the effect to the picture?

The normal css file look like this:

```
html,
body {
  font-size: 13;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: image.jpg;
}

img {
  display: none;
}
```

But if I also integrate this stylsheet to my website, all content is gone (invisible) and the effect is still no appearing...

How can I solve that?

Greetings and Thank You

Comment: First of all you should set a background-image like this:

background-image: url('image.jpg');
also you're telling your website to hide all Images on the website by saying:

img {
  display: none;
}
is that really what you want?

Comment: Since I don't know your script I also don't know how to add the effect to the site. Is the script documented anywhere? Or where did you get it from?

Comment: Have you considered a child theme - https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: here is the url from the script: https://codepen.io/chrisdoble/pen/WQLLVp